# Приведите, пожалуйста, максимально простой пример сортировки ArrayList с помощью Comparator

Tags: java, сортировка, list, arraylist, интерфейс

Посмотрел несколько статей по этой теме, но примеры, которые там приводятся, достаточно сложные для понимания, когда не разу ещё не работал с Comparator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Думаю можно предложить такой вариант.

```
class Person{
      
    private String name;
    Person(String name){
          
        this.name=name;
    }
    String getName(){return name;}
}

class PersonComparator implements Comparator<Person>{
 
    public int compare(Person a, Person b){
     
        return a.getName().compareTo(b.getName());
    }
}


PersonComparator pcomp = new PersonComparator();
List<Person> people = new ArrayList<Person>();
people.add(new Person("Tom"));
people.add(new Person("Nick"));
people.add(new Person("Alice"));
people.add(new Person("Bill"));

Collections.sort(people, pcomp);

for(Person  p : people){             
    System.out.println(p.getName());
}
```

Идея `Comparator` простая Вы используете для сравнения другой объект. Обычно это на случай когда вы не можете внести изменения в интересующий для вас класс с целью сравнения и вам необходима своя сообственная логика сравнения объектов.